# Can't run web application (Spring MVC, JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, maven-3

In my java project:

in pom.xml

```
<groupId>shop</groupId>
    <artifactId>shop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

and here controller:

```
@Controller
public class SellerController {

    @Autowired
    private SellerService sellerService;

    // handler methods will go here
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        List<Seller> listSeller = sellerService.listAll();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("listSeller", listSeller);
        return mav;
    }
}


public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    // The onStartup() method of this class will be automatically invoked by the
    // servlet container when the application is being loaded

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

In Spring controller:

```
 @Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.myproject.shop.seller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

I use SQLite db. File is in location: `WebContent/WEB-INF/data/shop.db`

In folder `WebContent/META-INF/persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="shop">
        <properties>
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:WEB-INF\data\shop.db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

File index.jsp in `WebContent/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`

Success build project by `mvn clean verify` and success deploy to Tomcat 9 (**shop.war**)

But when I try to open

```
http://localhost:8080/shop
```

I get 404 error.

```
Type Status Report

Message /shop

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Comment: Where's your controller, or the mapping of /shop ???

Comment: Check the answers, you don't have a mapping for /shop, or just try "http: //localhost:8080/"

Comment: @billalGHILAS Not help. Same result

Comment: Your `WebConfig` needs an `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. There is also an additional **space** in your `@ComponentScan`. Is the `@Controller` in the package you are scanning. Finally what is the name of the WAR you are deploying to tomcat? The name of the war is the root context. Judging from your pom I suspct the url to be something like http://localhost:8080/shop-0.0.1/. Also if you are really using Spring boot your `WebAppInitializer` is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum Not help. Same error

Comment: Does it even start? Also are you using Spring Boot? If so your starting class is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum Here log from Tomcat: 10-Dec-2019 16:28:02.926 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\Programs\apache-tomcat-9.0.16\webapps\shop.war] has finished in [3,616] ms. And no errors in Tomcat's logs

Comment: That doesn't state if it actually started, it should start the `DispatcherServlet`. But as mentioned / asked do you use Spring Boot or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show there is no mapping defined for the /shop endpoint.

I see your update, but there is still no mapping for /shop.

Try this:

```
@Controller
public class SellerController {

    @Autowired
    private SellerService sellerService;

    // handler methods will go here
    @RequestMapping("/shop") //<--HERE!!!
    public ModelAndView home() {
        List<Seller> listSeller = sellerService.listAll();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("listSeller", listSeller);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SellerController, instead of     @RequestMapping("/") do @RequestMapping("/shop")
that way, you will be pointing controller to listen to "/shop" and not on "/"

And onStartup on WebAppInitializer,add **dispatcher.addMapping("/shop");**

Comment: Not help. Same result

Answer (score -1):

View Resolver can be defined directly in **property** file like below

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Create a class annotate it with **@Controller** and follow below example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: Poster isn't using Spring Boot, your answer applies to Spring Boot not plain Spring.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum But question wasn't clarified... Let me update my answer as well :)